# on linux script can not find file but on windows it can

Tags: javascript, linux, file, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I have a script that needs a client_secret.json file and on windows the scipt can find it with no issues, but when i put it on my ubuntu server it gives an erro that it can't find the path.
Why is that?
mmy code looks like this:

```
fs.readFile('./client_secret.json', (err, content) => {
    if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
    // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Sheets API.
    authorize(JSON.parse(content), methodname);
  });
```

As I said on linux it runs onto the error branch, but on windows it works perfectly.

Comment: You’re probably running with a different working directory. Did you mean to read a file beside the script, as in `fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client_secret.json'), …`?

Comment: You might want to check whether the filename contains capital letters. File names in windows are case _in_sensitive while in linux/Unix they are case sensitive.

Comment: it is lowercase all around

Comment: the file is in the same folder as the script I had it previously without the './' but had the same effect

Answer (score 0):

this works: 
s.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client_secret.json')
don't forget to npm i path